# Differentiation - Power rule

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Find derivative of this function
$$g(t)=-3t(6t^4-1)^{4/3}$$
I have tried it till the answer:
$ -3t.\frac{4}{3} (6t^4 - 1)^{\frac{4}{3}-1} .\frac{d}{dt}(6t^4 -1)  $

$-3t x \frac{4}{3} (6t^4-1)^\frac{1}{3} ( 6X4 t^3 -0 ) $

$ -4t (6t^4 -1)^\frac{4}{3} (24t^3) $

$-96t(6t^4-1)^\frac{1}{3} $

However , I checked and saw that the answer is
$$-3(6t^4-1)^{1/3}(38t^4-1)$$
I just started learning differentiation, and I don't understand my mistake on why I can't achieve the answer. Thanks!

Comment: That's because you have to use the [product rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_rule).

Comment: You must use the product rule to also differentiate the $-3t$ term.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As there are two terms. You need to use product rule.

Product rule -

$(UV)' = UV' + U'V$

So it should be -

$g(t) = -3t(6t^4-1)^\frac{4}{3}$

$-3t.\frac{4}{3} (6t^4 - 1)^{\frac{4}{3}-1} .\frac{d}{dt}(6t^4 -1) - 3.\frac{d}{dt} t.(6t^4-1)^\frac{4}{3}$

Take common terms and simplify.

Comment: Your answer is correct but only one term is missing. See product rule.

Answer (score 1):

We can separate the $-3$ first:
$$g'(t)=-3(t(6t^4-1)^{4/3})'$$
Then apply the product rule and chain rule:
$$=-3(t'(6t^4-1)^{4/3}+t((6t^4-1)^{4/3})')$$
$$=-3((6t^4-1)^{4/3}+4/3\cdot t(6t^4-1)^{1/3}(6t^4-1)')$$
$$=-3((6t^4-1)^{4/3}+4/3\cdot t(6t^4-1)^{1/3}(24t^3))$$
Simplify:
$$=-3((6t^4-1)(6t^4-1)^{1/3}+4/3\cdot t(6t^4-1)^{1/3}(24t^3))$$
$$=-3((6t^4-1)^{1/3}(4/3\cdot t(24t^3)+6t^4-1))$$
$$=-3(6t^4-1)^{1/3}(32t^4+6t^4-1)$$
$$=-3(6t^4-1)^{1/3}(38t^4-1)$$

Answer (score 0):

after the product and the chain rule we get
$$-3(6t^4-1)^{4/3}-3t\frac{4}{3}(6t^4-1)^{1/3}\cdot 24t^3$$
after simplifying this derivative we get
$$-3 \sqrt[3]{6 t^4-1} \left(38 t^4-1\right)$$

Comment: this must only know the OP

Comment: i tried to multiply the $24t^3$ and I got $96t^4(6t^4-1)^1/3$ , then I simplified and reached $-3(6t^4 -1)^1/3 (32t^4 -(6t^4-1)). In that 2nd bracket , I'm not sure how to achieve $(38t^4-1)$